# How to monitor a system call?

Tags: system-calls

I have a problem, where an unknown process (in Linux) changes the permissions on certain files, and I am looking for a way to figure which process it may be. Ideally there would be a way to log all calls to a specific system call, with the PID, program name and timestamp; I imagine one could do this by hooking into the system call(s) and extracting the information needed before passing the call on to the kernel. Is there any such tool?

Comment: Have you done any searching to find this? Any examples you've tried?

Comment: I have, of course, searched in a number of places. Unfortunately, what I have found involves mostly thinks like strace or other techniques that require you to know which process is involved - my situation is different.

Answer (score 0):

From Server Fault question: [Unix filesystem hook](https://serverfault.com/questions/199710/unix-filesystem-hook)
answerd by [Steven Monday](https://serverfault.com/a/199713)
A tool call icron might help you.

Comment: Interesting - thank you! I think this might be it, and it even seems to be in Debian's package library.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n If this answer helped you, you might consider upvoting, and perhaps accepting it.

Comment: I tried, but for some reason it doesn't seem to do anything. I'll go and try from another browser.

Comment: oh, I see; I'm too disreputable, apparently - you need to have more than 15 point reputation it says (very, very briefly). Sorry about that.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n you should be able to accept the answer as correct.